# Unable to animate views in RecyclerView with ViewPropertyAnimator?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to fade in an image after it has been loaded in a view that is part of an other view inside a RecyclerView using the ViewPropertyAnimator. Looking at the debug output all looks quite fine, but the image remains invisible.

If I don't set the alpha value initially to 0, I can see that the image is loading and showing fine.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

```
    previewImage.setImageBitmap(image);
    previewImage.setAlpha(0);
    previewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    previewImage.animate()
            .setListener(this)
            .alpha(1.f)
            .setDuration(2400)
            .withEndAction(() -> Log.d(TAG, "Image alpha: " + previewImage.getAlpha() + ", visibility: " + previewImage.getVisibility()))
            .start();
```

Output with animation listeners in place:

```
main P(5): Image animation started  
main P(5): Image animation ended 
main P(5): Image alpha: 1.0, visibility: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
previewImage.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

The `ImageView` method `setAlpha(int)` was [deprecated in API 16](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29). So if you use just "0" instead of "0.0f", this older method is executed.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That worked. I've never thought that it could really make a difference how the alpha is set.